# C# Coroutine doesnt works in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Im trying to make a basic platformer game and my level controller script isnt working, it needs to load loading scene first and then nextlevel but it constantly loads the nextlevel

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string nextLevel;

    private Gem[] gems;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        gems = FindObjectsOfType<Gem>();    
    }

    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (ReadyToNextLevel())
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
            StartCoroutine(Wait());
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevel);
        }
    }

    bool ReadyToNextLevel()
    {
        foreach (var gem in gems)
        {
            if (gem.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two big issues in your code.

1. Starting a Coroutine does **not** delay the method that started the routine!

   If you want something happening after the Coroutine is finished you need to either move it into the routine itself or use a callback.
2. However, the thing is: You are loading a new scene, namely the "Loading" scene -> The current scene is unloaded -> the object this script is on gets destroyed -> the routine would no further executed.

   Except your object is `DontDestroyOnLoad` which seems not the case from your code.

---

So in order to solve both you will need to make sure this object is not destroyed when another scene is loaded, at least not until it finished the loading process.

You could do this like e.g.

```
public class LevelController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string nextLevel;

    private Gem[] gems;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        gems = FindObjectsOfType<Gem>();    

        // Makes sure this is not destroyed when another scene is load
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    bool alreadyLoading;

    IEnumerator Wait(Action whenDone)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        // invoke the callback action
        whenDone?.Invoke();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (ReadyToNextLevel() && ! alreadyLoading)
        {
            alreadyLoading = true;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
            StartCoroutine(Wait(() =>
            {
                // This will be done after the routine finished
                SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevel);

                // Now we don't need this object anymore
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }));
        }
    }

    bool ReadyToNextLevel()
    {
        foreach (var gem in gems)
        {
            if (gem.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: see derHugo's answer. They are more familiar with Unity than I am and point out that your script will be unloaded on scene change.

Your `Wait()` coroutine yields immediately, so `StartCoroutine(Wait())` will return immediately and load the next scene.

If you want to wait three seconds before loading, then put the load inside the coroutine.

Like this:

```
private bool isLoading;

void Update()
{
    if (!isLoading && ReadyToNextLevel())
        StartCoroutine(LoadNextLevel());
}

IEnumerator LoadNextLevel()
{
    isLoading = true;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevel);    
    isLoading = false;   
}
```

See [Coroutine help](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for more details

Comment: i tried some combinations but it still doesnt work can you explain how coroutines works? Maybe i can do this time

Comment: Have added example

Answer (score 0):

there are two reasons why this doesn't work, firstly when you load into the loading scene the gameObject is destroyed because you haven't told it to `DontDestroyOnLoad`, so the script will be sort of 'deleted' from the current scene. Second of all, when you call the coroutine, it calls the coroutine and then immediately continuous on to the next line of code, it doesn't wait for the coroutine to finish before moving on. I think derHugo covered how to fix these.